# common problems with images html

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer-8

Are there any common problems why alt attributes on images wont work.

Tested for IE8 Standards mode.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: What problem are you having?  Is this page in a public place where we can see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to show text from alt attrib, use `title=''` attrib.

The difference:

- alt shows up instead of img - when img cant load
- title shows up when you mouseover the image

Comment: It is interesting how VS2010 still uses the HTML schema with img/alt attribute and warns against not having the at attribute there.

Comment: in html specs alt is required attrib, title is only optional.

Comment: @Russell, the `alt` attribute *should* be there (for e.g. visually-impaired users).  It just doesn't mean the same thing as `title`.

Comment: @Matthew, good point. I was thinking he was more interested in the tooltip functionality. The alt and title should both be used if you want tooltip functionality and maximise accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

`alt` means just that, an alternative for when the image isn't displayed.  If you want a tooltip, use `title` or `longdesc`.  Historically `alt` has been abused to mean this, but IE8 has finally [fixed this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472%28VS.85%29.aspx#access).

Answer (score 0):

By "not work" I'm assuming you mean that the alt text doesn't appear when you hover over the image.  You'll need to use the title attribute if you always want the text to appear in all browsers:

```
<img src="foo.png" alt="bar" title="bar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always specify the `alt` attribute for these reasons:

- In case image is not found:

  - The text from `alt` will be shown instead
- The `alt` tag is important in terms of Search Engine Optimization (SEO)
- Accessibility reasons